# How can I stop NPCs from following me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I went on a killing-frenzy in Whiterun, all civilians are dead. I went in Jorrvaskr and I also went killing there, most of the people there are quest-characters so they were immortal. And now Aela the Huntress, Farkas and another guy are constantly following me with the question:

> I think you've been taking things from us that don't belong to you, pay your debts, and we will forget what happened.

I can choose between:

- Take your coin (money)
- Sorry (money)
- I'm paying nothing

But when I pay it, they keep following me. It's really annoying. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Have you tried fast-traveling?

Comment: You could always kill them, too.

Comment: Quest characters cannot be killed (as stated in the question).

Answer (score 3):

I'd try using the `disable` and then `enable` command on Aela the Huntress and each of the other unwanted followers. This should 'reset' them. Make sure you have a savegame before you try console commands, so you can revert to a previous save in case anything goes wrong or if it doesn't work.

Other console commands you might want to try: `paycrimegold <0-1> <0-1> 267EA` ('267EA' is Whiterun's faction ID - you could also try targeting each of the unwanted followers instead of a faction ID), `recycleactor` and `resetAI`. See if the issue persists after fast traveling.

`paycrimegold` pays your bounty and will help if the game or some NPCs consider you to have a bounty. `recycleactor` and `resetAI` are supposed to 'reset' an NPC.

More info on console commands here: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console_Commands

This similar question to yours, '[I have an imperial following me and I don't know how to shake him](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/82806/4797)' also has a solution that you might want to try if you'd rather not use console commands or are playing on a console (shamelessly quoting it here):

> I've had this problem on XBox, where Hadvar, the imperial who helps you (after trying to execute you) at the start of the game, would continuously follow me wherever I went after completing the civil war quest...
>
> First, move **very close** to him [the unwanted follower], up to the point where you are touching him. Then, **save your game**. Make sure you don't override a saved game in case this doesn't work. Then **shut off your console** completely and **reload the game you just saved**...
>
> If this doesn't work, I've heard people say that this can be fixed if you crouch when touching him before saving.

<sup>Originally posted by Nathan Sabruka at https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/82827/4797</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Console command **set playerfollowercount to <0>** should do it,try it few times it does't work always at first try also let some time pass.This returns followers to their place and occupation as they were before you ever met them.

**player.setrelationshiprank (targetID) <1-4>** Changes how much target "likes" you,this helps if yuo stole something of offended them somehow.

**Disable (targetID)** is last resort which should remove target from game completely.

More info on using console commands [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29)

Comment: i very much doubt either of these commands is going to fix it.

Comment: well they fix most of the follower problems,I should have mentioned that in extreme cases you could try using "Disable" command to remove target completely from game.

Comment: Which is the reason they wouldn't work in this case - they are not followers, they are stalkers.

Comment: setrelationship can affect targets other than followers if they use similar variables to determine their attitude.And Disable should even be usable on furniture...there also is the kill command that can be used on some immortal targets.

Comment: This appears to be a bounty problem (hence "you stole from us!"), not a relationship problem.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem. The NPCs would always follow me around and chase me out of Whiterun. I looked it up and some of the sources told me to clear all of my bounties. I had a 230k bounty, but I spent time in jail and now they don't follow me anymore.

I have no idea why this works but I would recommend it. :)

(I play on xbox)

Answer (score -1):

The only 2 ways to fix it without using the console is to kill them or go serve your time in jail or you can take them to the throat of the world and shout them off