# Why is this NPC following me?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

[image: ere is the picture]So I started the mission Daedra's Bestfriend. I am on my way to get the rueful axe when I saw a goat on the road, I killed it with Fus-Ro-Dah when suddenly a vampire NPC run towards me, I thought she will attack me but when I sheathe my bow she did the same to her dagger and she wont stop following and doing what I am doing... When I talk to her it just say "*This person is busy*".

I haven't started the **dawnguard** DLC mission yet.

I am curious what did I do to trigger this. Or is it just a random encounter?

Edit: I can now talk to her and command her like a companion after reloading a save file.

Comment: just a random (bug) encounter.

Comment: Please edit your question with the name of the vampire NPC. The game should show you their name or what type of NPC that is. Also, any mods installed? Some mods could affect NPC behavior.

Answer (score 1):

So after doing some research **generally it's either because of or related to mod issues or simply a vanilla bug**.

It's hard to give you an specific answer for your case because no idea which one is your case. That being said, most vanilla cases I found were related to having bounties and happened with random NPCs (which could be fixed by simply clearing all bounties) or were related to specific NPCs (fixed differently for each case). And in the case of mods it was always an specific mod issue (also with a particular fix).

**PS:** I know you didn't ask for a fix, but assuming you do want to fix it you can always try to just wait, sleep, reload a previous save or well, kill her lol. Or you can always try console commands. Anyway here are some sources: [1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/95920/how-can-i-stop-npcs-from-following-me), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/82806/i-have-an-imperial-following-me-and-i-dont-know-how-to-shake-him/82827#82827), [3](https://steamcommunity.com/app/72850/discussions/0/540741859475193881/), [4](https://www.loverslab.com/topic/116067-solved-how-to-stop-unwanted-npcs-following-me/).